# Problems when drawing text using the SpriteFont class

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

I'm using the SpriteFont/SpriteBatch classes to render text onto my game because quite frankly, i am tired of using Direct2D and DirectWrite... But everytime I draw text using SpriteFont, I get the text written on the screen, but it is written on a black background... The black background blocks the entire scene of my game.. is there any way to remove the black background and only keep the text?

Down below is my implementation of SpriteFont..

```
void RenderText(int FPS)
{

std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont> Sprite_Font(new DirectX::SpriteFont(device, L"myfile.spritefont"));

std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> Sprite_Batch(new DirectX::SpriteBatch(DevContext));

Sprite_Batch->Begin();

Sprite_Font->DrawString(Sprite_Batch.get(), L"FPS: ", DirectX::XMFLOAT2(200,200));

Sprite_Batch->End();


}
```

It seems to me that the black background is drawn because of the values that I specified in the function `ClearRenderTargetView()`.

```
float BackgroundColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

DevContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, BackgroundColor); //This is where the black background gets drawn over my entire scene
```

Everytime i change `BackgroundColor[4]` to different values, the background color changes as well, respectably. How can I remove the black background from my game and only include the text?

Here is my entire code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SpriteFont.h>
#include <SpriteBatch.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <SimpleMath.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, unsigned int, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void Create_Window(HINSTANCE&);
void Initialize_Direct3D11(HINSTANCE);
void Initialize_Rendering_Pipeline();
void Initialize_Sprites();
void Render_Frame();
void Render_Text();
void Create_Vertex_Buffer_for_triangle();

HWND MainWindow;
IDXGISwapChain * SwapChain;
ID3D11Device * device;
ID3D11DeviceContext * DevContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView * RenderTarget;
ID3D11Buffer * VertexBuffer;
ID3D10Blob * VertexShader;
ID3D10Blob * PixelShader;
ID3D11VertexShader * VS;
ID3D11PixelShader * PS;
ID3D11InputLayout * inputLayout;
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont> Sprite_Font;
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> Sprite_Batch;
DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 m_fontPos;
const wchar_t* output = L"Hello World";


struct Vertex_Buffer
{
 float Positions[3];


Vertex_Buffer(float x, float y, float z)
{
    Positions[0] = x;
    Positions[1] = y;
    Positions[2] = z;
};

};


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE CurrentInstance, HINSTANCE PrevInstance, LPSTR ignore, int WindowShow)
{
MSG message;
HRESULT status;

Create_Window(CurrentInstance);
Initialize_Direct3D11(CurrentInstance);
Initialize_Sprites();
Initialize_Rendering_Pipeline();
Create_Vertex_Buffer_for_triangle();


while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&message, MainWindow, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);

    }

    else
    {   
        Render_Frame();
        Render_Text();
        SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
    }

}

}

void Initialize_Sprites()
{
Sprite_Font.reset(new DirectX::SpriteFont(device, L"myfile.spritefont"));
Sprite_Batch.reset(new DirectX::SpriteBatch(DevContext));

m_fontPos.x = 200;
m_fontPos.y = 200;

}

void Create_Window(HINSTANCE &CurrentInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEX windowclass;                                 


ZeroMemory(&windowclass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
windowclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);                
windowclass.lpszClassName = L"Window Class";        
windowclass.hInstance = CurrentInstance;                
windowclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;              
windowclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);        
windowclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);      


RegisterClassEx(&windowclass);


MainWindow = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                                                  
    L"Window Class",                                    
    L"The Empire of Anatoria",                          
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                                
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                                      
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                                      
    800,                                                
    600,                                                
    NULL,                                               
    NULL,                                               
    CurrentInstance,                                    
    NULL                                                
    );


ShowWindow(MainWindow, SW_SHOW);
}

void Render_Text()
{
DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 origin = Sprite_Font->MeasureString(output);

Sprite_Batch->Begin();
Sprite_Font->DrawString(Sprite_Batch.get(), output,
    m_fontPos, DirectX::Colors::White, 0.f, origin);
Sprite_Batch->End();

}

void Initialize_Direct3D11(HINSTANCE instance) 
{
DXGI_MODE_DESC BackBufferDesc;
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC SwapChainDesc;



ZeroMemory(&BackBufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));
BackBufferDesc.Width = 400;                         
BackBufferDesc.Height = 400;                         
BackBufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;          
BackBufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;         
BackBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; 


ZeroMemory(&SwapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc = BackBufferDesc;      
SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;                          
SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                     
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;                   
SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = MainWindow;            
SwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;                          
SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;    



D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,                      
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,   
    NULL,                        
    NULL,                       
    NULL,                   
    NULL,                        
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,       
    &SwapChainDesc,          
    &SwapChain,             
    &device,                    
    NULL,                       
    &DevContext             
    );



ID3D11Texture2D * BackBuffer;
SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&BackBuffer);
device->CreateRenderTargetView(BackBuffer, NULL, &RenderTarget);
DevContext->OMSetRenderTargets(
            1,                            
            &RenderTarget,                  
            NULL                            
            );
BackBuffer->Release();

DevContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

}

void Initialize_Rendering_Pipeline()
{
D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", 0, 0, "main", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &VertexShader, 0);
D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", 0, 0, "Pixel_Shader", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &PixelShader, 0);

device->CreateVertexShader(VertexShader->GetBufferPointer(), VertexShader->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
device->CreatePixelShader(PixelShader->GetBufferPointer(), PixelShader->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

DevContext->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
DevContext->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);


D3D11_VIEWPORT Raster;

ZeroMemory(&Raster, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
Raster.MinDepth = 0.0f;
Raster.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
Raster.Width = 400;
Raster.Height = 400;
DevContext->RSSetViewports(1, &Raster);



D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC InputLayout[1];

ZeroMemory(&InputLayout[0], sizeof(D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC));
InputLayout[0].SemanticName = "POSITION";
InputLayout[0].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
InputLayout[0].InputSlot = 0;
InputLayout[0].AlignedByteOffset = 0;
InputLayout[0].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;

device->CreateInputLayout(
    InputLayout,
    1,
    VertexShader->GetBufferPointer(),
    VertexShader->GetBufferSize(),
    &inputLayout
    );
DevContext->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout);
}

void Render_Frame()
{
float BackgroundColor[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

DevContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, BackgroundColor);

DevContext->Draw(3, 0);

}

void Create_Vertex_Buffer_for_triangle()
{
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC VertexBufferDesc;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA VertexData;
UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex_Buffer);
UINT offset = 0;

ZeroMemory(&VertexBufferDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
VertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
VertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
VertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
VertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex_Buffer) * 3;


Vertex_Buffer VerticesData[] =
{
    Vertex_Buffer(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
    Vertex_Buffer(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f)
};


ZeroMemory(&VertexData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
VertexData.pSysMem = VerticesData;

device->CreateBuffer(
    &VertexBufferDesc,
    &VertexData,
    &VertexBuffer);

DevContext->IASetVertexBuffers(
    0,
    1,
    &VertexBuffer,
    &stride,
    &offset
    );

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND handle, unsigned int message, WPARAM ignore1, LPARAM ignore2)
{
switch (message)
{

case WM_CREATE:
    return 0;


case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(handle);
    return 0;


default:
    return DefWindowProc(handle, message, ignore1, ignore2);
}


}
```

Here is the VertexShader.hlsl file

```
float4 main( float4 pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
return pos;
}

float4 Pixel_Shader() : SV_TARGET
{
return float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Try using a call to `Begin` for sprite batch with `AlphaBlend` for the blend state (or possibly `NonPremultiplied`). Just a guess -- this is outside of my area, but was digging through the docs trying to look for a transparent drawing mode.

Comment: I have already tried setting a blend state to make the background transparent, but it still doesn't work. The background still blocks the entire scene

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Comment: Apologies -- that was my only one. I've never worked with this API, but I hope someone who has will notice this thread and jump in.

Comment: Where is the ``VertexShader.hlsl`` file coming from? It appears to have both your vertex and pixel shader in it, although it might not since you don't have any error checking on the call to ``D3DCompileFromFile``

Comment: I included the `VertexShader.hlsl` in the original post. And yes you are right, i will check all the functions for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your code snippet is accurate, you should not be creating the `SpriteFont` and `SpriteBatch` instance every frame. You only have to create them when the device changes.

By default, `SpriteFont` is drawing using pre-multiplied alpha blending modes, so if you are getting a fully "background color" image then something else is amiss in your pipeline state. It is likely that you are leaving some state in effect in the rendering between the clear and `RenderText` that is affecting the `SpriteBatch` renderer that you should reset.

It might also be the color you are using for the background clear which has the alpha set to 0 rather than 1. Try using:

```
float BackgroundColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
```

> Try working through a few of the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) to make sure things are working in isolation and so you understand how the classes work, specifically [Drawing text](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Drawing-text).

Comment: I went to the tutorials and I think i have a better understanding on these classes. But i have a question, when should I `reset()` the `SpriteBatch` and `SpriteFont` instances? Should i reset them in the game loop?

Comment: You should only need to ``reset()`` the ``std::unique_ptr<T>`` in the  'device lost' scenario (i.e. ``Present`` returned ``DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED`` or ``DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET`` which means the device is invalid and _everything_ based on the Direct3D device has to be thrown away and recreated with a new device instance). Look closely at the [basic game loop](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/The-basic-game-loop) lesson.

Comment: I followed every step in the tutorials but the black back ground persist. I even made a new application that just draws a red triangle, and once i made the sprites, the black background covers the triangle. I included the code of my new application in my original post, if you have spare time, can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: The first thing you should do with your code is make sure to check the ``HRESULT`` return from all functions that return one: ``HRESULT hr = /* Direct3D Function */; if (FAILED(hr)) /* error */`` Your code snippet above has basically no error checking, so you won't get notified when something goes wrong. Second, you need to enable the Direct3D debug device by passing ``D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`` as the fourth parameter to ``D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain``. See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You and me have the same problem with `SpriteFont`. We forgot to reset the `VertexBuffer`s and all other rendering states after the call to `SpriteFont`. See my post and the solution from *Chuck Walbourn*: [DirectX::SpriteFont/SpriteBatch prevents 3D scene from drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558178/directxspritefont-spritebatch-prevents-3d-scene-from-drawing).

To quote Chuck:

> You set the render state up for your scene in InitScene, but drawing anything else changes the state which is exactly what SpriteBatch does. I document which render states each object in DirectX Toolkit manipulates on the wiki. You need to set all the state your Draw requires each frame, not assume it is set forever, if you do more than a single draw.

See my question for additional links providing more information.