# Why sprites render over objects?

Tags: directx, spritebatch, directxtk

I want to render a cube on a picture like in this [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Writing-custom-shaders). Problem is that it renders only the picture and the cube doesn't render. Can you help me ? Thankyou

```
m_spriteBatch->Begin();
m_spriteBatch->Draw(m_background.Get(), m_fullscreenRect);

//
// Clear the back buffer
//
g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, Colors::MidnightBlue );

g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, g_pDepthStencilView);


//
// Update variables
//
ConstantBuffer cb;
cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose( g_World );
cb.mView = XMMatrixTranspose( g_View );
cb.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose( g_Projection );
g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( g_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb, 0, 0 );

//
// Renders a triangle
//
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed( 36, 0, 0 );        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list

//
// Present our back buffer to our front buffer
//
m_spriteBatch->End();
g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpriteBatch` batches up draws for performance, so it's likely being drawn *after* the cube draw. If you want to make sure the sprite background draws first, then you need to call `End` before you submit your cube. You also need to call `Begin` *after* you set up the render target:

```
// Clear
g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, g_pDepthStencilView);

// Draw background image
m_spriteBatch->Begin();
m_spriteBatch->Draw(m_background.Get(), m_fullscreenRect);
m_spriteBatch->End();

// Draw objects
context->OMSetBlendState(…);
context->OMSetDepthStencilState(…);
context->IASetInputLayout(…);
context->IASetVertexBuffers(…);
context->IASetIndexBuffer(…);
context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(…);
```

> You can omit the `ClearRenderTargetView` if the `m_background` texture covers the whole screen.

For more on how `SpriteBatch` draw order and batching works, see the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch#sorting).

Comment: Thankyou for answering so fast. I did all you said but it's not working, I mention that I draw the object like in this example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff729722.aspx), not using shape draw.

Comment: I think it's related to this, I am not sure https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31616/spritebatch-begin-making-my-model-not-render-correctly

Comment: Your answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558178/directxspritefont-spritebatch-prevents-3d-scene-from-drawing) is related to this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558178/directxspritefont-spritebatch-prevents-3d-scene-from-drawing) by @ChuckWalbourn I fixed the problem.

```
 g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, Colors::MidnightBlue );


g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | 

D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);


m_spriteBatch->Begin();
m_spriteBatch->Draw(m_background.Get(), m_fullscreenRect);
m_spriteBatch->End();

states = std::make_unique<CommonStates>(g_pd3dDevice);
g_pImmediateContext->OMSetBlendState(states->Opaque(), Colors::Black, 0xFFFFFFFF);
g_pImmediateContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(states->DepthDefault(), 0);
// Set the input layout
g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pVertexLayout);
UINT stride = sizeof(SimpleVertex);
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
// Set index buffer
g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

// Draw objects
```

Comment: I'd recommend not creating a new ``CommonStates`` object every frame. Creating Direct3D resource objects can be expensive, so you don't want to do it 60+ times a second if you don't need to. Make it a member variable like you have ``SpriteBatch``, etc.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for your help. Btw, do you think I can get the same effect using firect composition ?